Itch.io anti-piracy measures?
I'm beginning to develop an online party-style game that is planned to be launched initially on itch.io. It's important to note that this game will be unplayable without a connection to the online servers that run it. I'm currently working through early stages of planning, and I was thinking a bit about piracy.
My main question is this: Can itch.io give a user who bought my game a unique download key specific to their purchase, and give a list of these keys by way of an API call?
Here's my vision:

Itch gives users a unique key that is specific to their purchase of my game, which they will then input into the game upon first launch. This will be sent to the server, which will authenticate their purchase through the itch.io API.

The game will store this key and send it automatically upon each launch to authenticate with the server.

If the server ever gets two clients using the same key at the same time, it'll know something is wrong and deny them access.


The only thing I'm not sure about is if users can access the download key associated with their purchase of my game. Or even if there's there's a way to automate it, like having Itch somehow give the key to the game when it runs?
Is there a way to do this?

This documentation on the itch.io API looks like it would be useful for your purpose.

From the linked docs, it says you can authenticate a user’s itch.io account and receive a proof of purchase. Surely that’s a good starting point :)

An answer explaining how to use the API documented above to implement this feature would still be valuable, as it does not seem to be clearly spelled out as an example (at least not at the cursory reading I gave it).
